# SQL Pivot/Transform

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012, I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataField](
    [DisplayName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayValue] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I run this insert query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DataField VALUES 
('Column 1', '10'),
('Column 2', '20'),
('Column 1', '30'),
('Column 2', '40'),
('Column 1', '50'),
('Column 2', '60'),
('Column 1', '70'),
('Column 2', '80')
```

I run this query...

```
SELECT DisplayName, DisplayValue FROM [dbo].[DataField]
```

Which returns

```
Field      |   Value
'Column 1' |    10
'Column 2' |    20
'Column 1' |    30
'Column 2' |    40
'Column 1' |    50
'Column 2' |    60
```

I would like to write a query that outputs the results like this..

```
Column 1 | Column 2
10       | 20
30       | 40
50       | 60
```

Can I do this using Pivot or Unpivot or some other tsql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In @BogdanSahlean's answer, instead of `row_number` you may also use `dense_rank` like:

```
SELECT z.[Column A], z.[Column B]
FROM (
    SELECT x.DisplayName, x.DisplayValue, x.GroupNum
    FROM (
        SELECT  *
                , (DENSE_RANK() 
                   OVER(PARTITION BY df.DisplayName 
                        ORDER BY df.DataFieldID)) AS GroupNum
        FROM     @t df
    ) x
) y
PIVOT( MAX(y.DisplayValue) FOR y.DisplayName IN ([Column A], [Column B]) ) z;
```

Comment: Thank you both very much. O